# How to write new data to an existing excel spreadsheet column?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

After doing some sort of operation between two columns I want to then update the Y/N? column with the result of the operation performed on the Connector/Pin cols. How do I write data to only this column in the excel sheet? Anything I have found online seems kind of vague and I am not the biggest master of python.

```
Connector  Pin Color  Y/N?
0       1    1     R   NaN
1       5    2     O   NaN
2       3    3     Y   NaN
3       2    4    GR   NaN
4       1    5     L   NaN
5       3    6     R   NaN
6       4    7     B   NaN
7       6    8     L   NaN
8       8    9    GR   NaN
9       9   10     O   NaN
10      7    1     R   NaN
11      0    2     R   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, Stock Overflow is a place to look for answers to problems not for written solutions. However, i will be kind enough to provide you with some insight on where to start...

Second off, why do you think you need to use Python for this? Unless there is a valid reason to use Python, then I would stick with what is available within Excel.

I would suggest searching for Excel IF statements. IF statements will be able to provide you the results you want. You could even nest multiple IF Statements (or you could write your own VBA Function).

Comment: My example above is a pretty watered down version of what I am working on and the solution I am looking for guidance on is a small chunk of my overall problem I am trying to solve. But long story short I am writing a script that takes data from multiple spreadsheets, does some work on it all, and then spits it back out to another spreadsheet. I am not looking for a written solution, only a push in the right direction.

Comment: If you are using Python to generate this excel spreed sheet, then why not have Python compare these values, and then write the correct data to the specific data column. Both Python and Excel support If functions that can help give you the proper results for each row.